# hash tables (Closed addressing). How to initialize and print?

Tags: c++, c, hash

How should i deal with a hash table for closed addressing?

Data structure:

```
typedef char ktype[9];
typedef void *Infoc;

typedef struct entryc{
    ktype ckey;
    Infoc infoc;
    struct entryc *next;
} Entryc;

typedef Entryc *Chashtable[HASHSIZE];
```

I am declaring a pointer of an array of structs, initialized:

```
void initChain(Chashtable *h){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++){
        *h[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

This is the insertion code:

```
void insertChain(Chashtable *h, ktype k, Infoc inf){
    int n= hash(k, 0);
    char hkey[3];
    sprintf(hkey, "%d", n);
    struct entryc *new = malloc (sizeof(struct entryc));
    strcpy(new->ckey, hkey);
    new->infoc = inf;
    new->next = *h[n];
    *h[n] = new;
}
```

And i would like to print out the hash table:

```
void printChain(Chashtable *h){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++){
        if((*h[i])){
        printf("-> %s\n", (*h[i])->ckey);
        }
    }
}
```

I get a segmentation fault while printing, why?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Complete code with segmentation fault (No other errors in the debugger found):

**

> Full compilable code here:

**
http://pastebin.com/GHpfqmP3

Comment: Have you run your program in a debugger to help you find the problem yourself? At the minimum it will tell you the line of code which causes the seg fault. If you really need help then please post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With `char hkey[3]; sprintf(hkey, "%d", n);` will `n` always be a 2-digit number? The `struct` field allows for an 8-digit number, you have `strcpy(new->ckey, hkey);` Should `hkey` be `ktype hkey` to match the `struct` field?

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for the tip, i will post a minimal complete and verifiable example in the next 5 min.

Comment: @WeatherVane hkey corresponds to hashed key, in fact the size of the table is only 31 (academical purposes only, not real world implementation), so that string hkey[3] is enough.

Comment: Looing at the code link, don't you `#include` any library headers?

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm such a fool. Added now.

Comment: Use `new`, not `malloc` in C++ code.  It's less error-prone.  watch out for your pointer indirections.

Answer (score 1):

You have your pointers all wrong for function args and implementation. `Chashtable` is an array of `struct` pointers. I removed one level of indirection everywhere and the code now runs, perhaps not as you would like! BTW I had to patch in a `hash()` function. I hope you can take this on from here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define HASHSIZE 31
#define EMPTY   " "
#define DELETED "-"

typedef char ktype[9];
typedef void *Infoc;

typedef struct entryc{
    ktype ckey;
    Infoc infoc;
    struct entryc *next;
} Entryc;

typedef Entryc *Chashtable[HASHSIZE];

int hash(ktype k, int z) {
   return rand() % HASHSIZE;
}

void initChain(Chashtable h){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++){
        h[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void printChain(Chashtable h){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<HASHSIZE; i++){
        if((h[i])){
        printf("-> %s\n", (h[i])->ckey);
        }
    }
}

void insertChain(Chashtable h, ktype k, Infoc inf){
    int n= hash(k, 0);
    char hkey[3];
    sprintf(hkey, "%d", n);
    struct entryc *new = malloc (sizeof(struct entryc));
    strcpy(new->ckey, hkey);
    new->infoc = inf;
    new->next = h[n];
    h[n] = new;
}

int main(void) {
    // system ("tput clear");

    Chashtable j;
    initChain(j);
    printChain(j);
    insertChain(j, "myname", "single");
    printChain(j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to both assign (in initialize) and then check (in print) the value of `h[i]` rather than `*h[i]`.

As a side, your insert seems spotty, too.  If nothing else, almost all of C compilers are C++ compilers and `new` is a C++ keyword.  So it's a bad idea to name your C  variables by that name.